Flutter UI Screen doesn't update
I am new to Flutter and need some help. I am working on an App to choose between Eating Plans. In the setting screen I want the user to be able to make some changes on the plans. You can klick on a weekday and edit the eating plan for that day.
The changes are showing correctly in the UI and database, but when I switch to another weekday and back to the edited weekday, the changes are not made and are back to what it was before.
When I leave the whole screen and go back to that edited weekday, the changes are shown. Just when I switch between the weekdays, they are not and I don't know why.
On the other side, the changes on the Chips for the kalendar weeks (Kalenderwochen) are correctly shown always.
class EatingPlanForm extends StatefulWidget {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> formKey;
  final int speiseplanIndex;
  final FirestoreEatingPlanRepository firestoreEatingPlanRepository;
  EatingPlan selectedEatingPlan;
  final void Function(EatingPlan) onEatingPlanUpdated;
  final TextEditingController kalenderwocheController;

  EatingPlanForm({
    super.key,
    required this.formKey,
    required this.speiseplanIndex,
    required this.firestoreEatingPlanRepository,
    required this.selectedEatingPlan,
    required this.onEatingPlanUpdated,
    required this.kalenderwocheController,
  });

  @override
  State<EatingPlanForm> createState() => _EatingPlanFormState();
}

class _EatingPlanFormState extends State<EatingPlanForm> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return Form(
      key: widget.formKey,
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          _buildChipsForKalenderwochen(),
          CustomTextField(
            label: 'Mittagessen 1',
            initialValue: widget.selectedEatingPlan.mittagessen1,
            mealType: 'mittagessen1',
            onChanged: (value) => _updateMeal('mittagessen1', value),
          ),
          CustomTextField(
            label: 'Mittagessen 2',
            initialValue: widget.selectedEatingPlan.mittagessen2 ?? '',
            mealType: 'mittagessen2',
            onChanged: (value) => _updateMeal('mittagessen2', value),
          ),
          CustomTextField(
            label: 'Mittagessen 3',
            initialValue: widget.selectedEatingPlan.mittagessen3 ?? '',
            mealType: 'mittagessen3',
            onChanged: (value) => _updateMeal('mittagessen3', value),
          ),
          CustomTextField(
            label: 'Beilagensalat',
            initialValue: widget.selectedEatingPlan.beilagensalat ?? '',
            mealType: 'beilagensalat',
            onChanged: (value) => _updateMeal('beilagensalat', value),
          ),
          CustomTextField(
            label: 'Nachtisch',
            initialValue: widget.selectedEatingPlan.nachtisch ?? '',
            mealType: 'nachtisch',
            onChanged: (value) => _updateMeal('nachtisch', value),
          ),
          CustomTextField(
            label: 'Abendessen 1',
            initialValue: widget.selectedEatingPlan.abendessen1,
            mealType: 'abendessen1',
            onChanged: (value) => _updateMeal('abendessen1', value),
          ),
          CustomTextField(
            label: 'Abendessen 2',
            initialValue: widget.selectedEatingPlan.abendessen2 ?? '',
            mealType: 'abendessen2',
            onChanged: (value) => _updateMeal('abendessen2', value),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              if (widget.formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                await widget.firestoreEatingPlanRepository.updateEatingPlan(widget.selectedEatingPlan);
                FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text('Speiseplan aktualisiert')));
              }
            },
            child: const Text('Speiseplan aktualisieren'),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () => _showDeleteConfirmationDialog(context),
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.red),
            child: const Text('Speiseplan löschen'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _updateMeal(String mealType, String value) {
    setState(() {
      widget.selectedEatingPlan = widget.selectedEatingPlan.copyWith(
        wochentag: mealType == 'wochentag' ? value : null,
        mittagessen1: mealType == 'mittagessen1' ? value : null,
        mittagessen2: mealType == 'mittagessen2' ? value : null,
        mittagessen3: mealType == 'mittagessen3' ? value : null,
        beilagensalat: mealType == 'beilagensalat' ? value : null,
        nachtisch: mealType == 'nachtisch' ? value : null,
        abendessen1: mealType == 'abendessen1' ? value : null,
        abendessen2: mealType == 'abendessen2' ? value : null,
      );
    });
    setState(() {
      widget.onEatingPlanUpdated(widget.selectedEatingPlan);
    });
  }
Widget _buildChipsForKalenderwochen() {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Wrap(
          spacing: 4.0,
          runSpacing: 4.0,
          children: widget.selectedEatingPlan.kalenderwochen.map((kw) {
            return Chip(
              label: Text('KW $kw'),
              onDeleted: () async {
                try {
                  await widget.firestoreEatingPlanRepository.deleteKalenderwoche(
                    widget.speiseplanIndex,
                    widget.selectedEatingPlan.wochentag,
                    kw,
                  );
                  setState(() {
                    widget.selectedEatingPlan.kalenderwochen.remove(kw);
                  });
                  if (widget.formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                    await widget.firestoreEatingPlanRepository.updateEatingPlan(widget.selectedEatingPlan);
                  } else {
                    print("Fehler");
                  }
                } catch (e) {
                    print("Fehler beim Löschen der Kalenderwoche: $e");
                  }
                },
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
        const SizedBox(width: 8.0), // Abstand zwischen den Chips und dem Textfeld
        SizedBox(
          width: 100.0, // Festlegen einer festen Breite für das Textfeld
          height: 32.0,
          child: TextField(
            controller: widget.kalenderwocheController,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'KW',
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () async {
            final kalenderwoche = int.tryParse(widget.kalenderwocheController.text);
            if (kalenderwoche != null && !widget.selectedEatingPlan.kalenderwochen.contains(kalenderwoche)) {
              try {
                await widget.firestoreEatingPlanRepository.addKalenderwoche(
                  widget.speiseplanIndex,
                  widget.selectedEatingPlan.wochentag,
                  kalenderwoche,
                );
                setState(() {
                  widget.selectedEatingPlan.kalenderwochen.add(kalenderwoche);
                });
                widget.kalenderwocheController.clear();
                if (widget.formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                  await widget.firestoreEatingPlanRepository.updateEatingPlan(widget.selectedEatingPlan);
                } else {
                  print("Fehler");
                }
              } catch (e) {
                print("Fehler beim Hinzufügen der Kalenderwoche: $e");
                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                  const SnackBar(content: Text('Fehler beim Hinzufügen der Kalenderwoche')),
                );
              }
            }
          }
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}


And this is my CustomTextField
class CustomTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  final String label;
  final String initialValue;
  final String mealType;
  final void Function(String) onChanged;

  const CustomTextField({super.key, required this.label, required this.initialValue, required this.onChanged, required this.mealType});
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController(text: initialValue);

    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: controller,
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: label),
                onChanged: (value) => onChanged(value),
              ),
            ),
          ]
        )
      ]
    );
  }
}

I tried making the CustomTextField a Stateful Widget but that didn't help either.
I am expecting that the changes the user makes are shown correctly in the UI independent of switching the screens.

Don't use setState to update values from the widget parameters. Use it exclusively to update states that you define inside the state class.
